# Load views into special controlAggregations of SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I found that the SAPUI5 router will not load views into some types of controlAggregations:

I could successfully load views into controlAggregations of type `pages`, `masterPages`, `detailsPages` and `content`.

But I could not for example load a view into controlAggregation `items` of an `IconTabBar`. Trying this throws the following error:

```
Element sap.m.IconTabFilter#__filter0" is not valid for aggregation
"content" of Element sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView#__component0---tabInfo
```

`IconTabFilter` in the error message is the outermost control of the view that I try to load. This is the correct type of control for an `IconTabBar`, and works nicely if I insert it directly into the parent view. Notice the `aggregation "content"` in the error message. This is not correct - I definitely told to load into `items`!

So I conclude that it is simply not possible to load target views into *any* type of aggregation through the router. Am I right, or did I do something wrong here? And is there a list of allowed controlAggregation types that the router can handle? I could not find anything about it.

Comment: i think the "content" in the error message belongs to the view element, so you cant load the views content element into the the IconTabFilter. But why do you want to achieve this? There may be easier solutions for your usecase

Comment: can you share your manifest.json to show the routing definition ?